# How can I group by date of range between start time and end time in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I trying to create a calendar list

Migrate:

```
class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :start_time
      t.datetime :end_time

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% @dates.each do |day, posts| %>
 <%for daytime in day%>
  <h4 class="other_day_title"><%= daytime %></h4>
  <% posts.each do |post| %>
   <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %></p>
  <%end%>
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Controller:

```
def index
@posts = Post.all.order(:start_time)
@date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
@dates = @posts.group_by {|t| t.start_time.to_date..t.end_time.to_date}
end
```

The output is:

[image]

Two posts is overlap

How can I display this:

2016-02-09

- test1

2016-02-10

- test1
- test2

2016-02-11

- test1
- test2

2016-02-12

- test1
- test2

Comment: the desired keys for the group by are the `start_time`?

Comment: @gamliar, I think is the date range from start_time to end_time

Comment: and what does @dates return?

Comment: Maybe `@dates = [[2016-02-09..2016-02-10],[2016-02-10..2016-02-11],[2016-02-11..2016-02-12],[2016-02-12..2016-02-14]]` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@dates = @posts.map { |post| (post.start_time.to_date..post.end_time.to_date).to_a }.flatten.uniq
```

Then, in your view:

```
<% @dates.each do |day| %>
  <h4 class="other_day_title"><%= day %></h4>
  <% @posts.select { |post| ((post.start_time.to_date..post.end_time.to_date).to_a).include? day }.each do |post| %>
    <p class="post_title">。<%= post.title %></p>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Since `@dates` now only has the dates, you iterate through those. Then for each of those, you select each post where that day is in the range of its `start_time.to_date..end_time.to_date`, so that it will list each post that was happening on that date.

**Edit**
`@dates` now includes every date that is in any range of `start_time.to_date..end_time.to_date` for any given object. It then flattens the array and selects only the unique elements, iterating over those in the view.

Comment: I know that, but I wonder group by start time and end time date

Comment: ...and just edited out a careless syntax error on my part. Sorry if you saw it before that last edit.

Comment: there's a problem of that. It can't display the period between start time and end time, **2016-02-11** this date bar is gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103541/discussion-between-champer-wu-and-michael-cruz).

Answer (score 0):

I think `group` is not quite what you want to achieve. What about doing it this way:

```
@dates =  @posts.each_with_object({}) do |post, acc|
  (post.start_date..post.end_date).each do |date|
    (acc[date] ||= []) << post
  end
end
```